# iOS Mail does not update in background

Tags: ios, email, ipod-touch, mobile-mail

I have been using my 6th generation iPod touch for a few years and the pre-installed mail application had been working just fine until a couple weeks ago. Normally I would unlock my iPod and see a notification if I received an email or not but now I have to manually go into the app and refresh it myself. I looked in the settings and there was nothing that I saw that I thought could fix it. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: What email service do you use?

Comment: The service I use is Yahoo